# Display 2 filtered columns from 2 tables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables - users and users_audit, need to display results from 2 separate queries into 2 columns with relation to each other. I already figured out both queries.

query for users: `SELECT rowid,data FROM users WHERE columnid = 1 GROUP BY rowid;`

```
+-------+------------+
| rowid | data       |
+-------+------------+
|     1 | John       |
|     2 | Abi        |
|     3 | Tony       |
|     4 | Gregg      |
|     5 | Jon        |
|     6 | Victor     |
|     7 | Daniel     |
```

query for users_audit: `SELECT date_created FROM users_audit WHERE rowid = 6 ORDER BY date_created DESC, date_created DESC LIMIT 1;`

Purpose of the query is to display latest date_created for particular rowid.

```
+---------------------+
| date_created        |
+---------------------+
| 2012-07-04 09:20:12 |
+---------------------+
```

Table users_audit looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users_audit;

+-------+---------+--------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  id   |  rowid  | before_value | after_value | date_created        |
+-------+---------+--------------+-------------+---------------------+
|     1 |       6 | 3            | 5           | 2012-06-29 15:48:11 |
|     2 |       5 | Out (0)      | 2           | 2012-07-04 09:20:10 |
|     3 |       6 | 5            | 4           | 2012-07-04 09:20:12 |
|     4 |       7 | 3            | 6           | 2012-07-04 09:20:14 |
|     5 |       3 | 2            | 3           | 2012-07-04 09:20:16 |
|     6 |      15 | 6            | 5           | 2012-07-04 09:20:22 |
```

I need to display 2 columns - data from users and date_created from users_audit for each rowid. It means query for users_audit must be run for each rowid (in the loop?).

Expected result displayed in php is:

```
+------------+----------------------+
| data       | date_created         |
+------------+----------------------+
| John       | (latest date)        |
| Abi        | (latest date)        |
| Tony       | (latest date)        |
| Gregg      | (latest date)        |
| Jon        | (latest date)        |
| Victor     | 2012-07-04 09:20:12  |
| Daniel     | (latest date)        |
```

How can this be achieved this in php?

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just create a view and use a join to create the table you want?

```
 SELECT users.data, users_audit.date_created FROM users 
     INNER JOIN users_audit ON users.rowid = users_audit.rowid
```

Or am I missing something here?

EDIT

```
 SELECT users.data, users_audit.date_created FROM users 
     INNER JOIN users_audit ON users.rowid = users_audit.rowid
     WHERE users_audit.date_created = (SELECT MAX(date_created) from users_audit
 GROUP BY rowid)
```

I believe this should work..? Let me know.

Comment: that is not bad, almost there, the one issue is that this query will display both id 1 and 3 for rowid 6(Victor), I want to display only latest record for each rowid - it is represented by highest id or most recent date in users_audit, also need to keep this portion of first statement WHERE columnid = 1 GROUP BY rowid as it filters the users table (it has many more records)... thanks

Comment: so following worked for me to some extend: 
SELECT users.data, users_audit.date_created FROM users 
     INNER JOIN users_audit ON users.rowid = users_audit.rowid 
     WHERE columnid = 1; 

but still need to display only latest date for each users_audit.rowid, any idea?

Comment: ill try and revise my answer for max date

Comment: hi it does not seem to be working, it gives: ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: if I remove GROUP BY rowid, then I get multiple results but only for rowid 13(the last person editing the table..)

Comment: Leaving the "Where" statement and keeping just "GROUP BY rowid" gives me expected result of the table - all users listed(each just once), but the oldest date displayed rather than most recent..